# Javascript mouseover duplicate content

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, duplicates

There are two buttons. When they indicate to each button, they will show different content from the database. The problem is that when I move to Emergency button, it can show the result.

But, if I move to Regular button, it will add the result in the table  (Emergency + Regular result).  However, I want to divide the result when mouseover different button.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#Emergency").one('mouseover', (function () {
            Emergency()-- > function written by ajax
    }));
});

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#Regular").one('mouseover', (function () {
            Regular()-- > function written by ajax
    }));
});
```

Comment: `when they indicate to each button, they will show different content from database` what does this mean?

Comment: without a hint of the content of `Emergency()` and `Regular()` - any answer would be pure speculation. When asking for help, it's often a good idea to pretend we can't see the code you don't post

Comment: Emergency button show result  123      but if i move to Regular button , it own result 234  ...  but now    it has two result  123 + 234

Comment: that mean duplicate call

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Emergency() and Regular() functions use sort of same js variable or same success function.

Comment: Then try to separate them. If you don't know how - please provide code for Emergency() and Regular()

Comment: but can i know what is the problem of it?

Comment: I can't tell you exactly until I know how does your client code work. If you can't provide code - try do debug "success" functions from browser.